# i write a calculator.everything work,but when i want use dot '.' for Decimals its jump out.i cant understand whats wrong

Tags: c#

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double resualt,oprand1,oprand;
        char oprand2;

 private void Dot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tb.Text += dot.Text;
            
        }
 private void B1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tb.Text += b1.Text;
        }

 private void Sum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            oprand1 += double.Parse(tb.Text);
            tb.Clear();
            oprand2 = '+';
        }
   private void Rzat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            oprand = double.Parse(tb.Text);
            switch(oprand2)
            {
                case '+':
                {
                    resualt = oprand1 + oprand;
                    break;
                }
                case '-':
                 {
                        resualt = oprand1 - oprand;
                        break;
                 }
              
            }
            oprand1 = 0;
            tb.Text = resualt.ToString();
        }
```

i write code for all number and + - * / but i cant use dot'.'every thing work until i use for example 4.5+ and its jump out and give me a error! [image]

Comment: Why do you want to use `.` for decimals? It sounds like the regional settings on your computer (and therefore the culture assumed by the application when you start it) uses `,` for decimals. Unless you're dealing with external data in a specific format, it would be much more natural for your user to input numbers in the regular format for their culture.

Comment: to @John's point if you try a "comma" in your textbox does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [double.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Double_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) with [InvariantCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=netcore-3.1#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_InvariantCulture).

```
oprand1 += double.Parse(tb.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```